# Get details from google places

Tags: javascript, api, request, response, google-places-api

I need to get details for object with Google places.
I need opening_hours so I write this:

SO on my code I add request for place, service and getDetails function

```
 markers = [];
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
     var image = {
         url: place.icon,
         size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
         origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
         anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
         scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
     };
     //CODE THAT I WRITE TO GET DETAILS FOR PLACE
     var request = {
         reference: place.reference
     };
     var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
     service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
         var open = '';
         try {
             open = place.opening_hours.periods[1].open.time;
         } catch (e) {
             open = 'No work time';
         }
         var otvoreno = place.openNow + "</br>" + place.name;
         // Create a marker for each place.
         var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
             map: map,
             icon: image,
             title: place.name,
             position: place.geometry.location,
             labelContent: open,
             labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
             labelStyle: {
                 opacity: 0.75
             },
             labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0)
         });
     });
     markers.push(marker);
     bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
 }
```

but I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openNow' of null
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try open_now instead of openNow.

You can reference this answer to examine your complete response:

[Loop through nested objects with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546739/loop-through-nested-objects-with-jquery?rq=1)