# Create nested UL lists with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assuming I have the following object:

```
var data =
[
{"x.y":"X Y"},
{"x.y.a":"X Y A"},
{"x.y.b":"X Y B"},
{"x.y.c":"X Y C"},
{"d.e":"D E"}
];
```

How can render them in HTML like the following with jQuery?

```
x:
 y:"X Y"
  a:"X Y A"
  b:"X Y B"
  c:"X Y C"
d:
 e:"D E"
```

Comment: What is the data? are you trying to create an array of nested object? If so, this is not correct.

Comment: The data is returned from an ajax call. It is an array of objects. I need to render them on the front end according to the json 'key' name.

Comment: It does not matter where the data is coming from. variable data does not have a valid structure. fix it and then we can have a nice loop to generate li list

Comment: look into this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546739/loop-through-nested-objects-with-jquery

Comment: {
  "x.y": "X Y",
  "x.y.a": "X Y A",
  "x.y.b": "X Y B",
  "x.y.c": "X Y C",
  "d.e": "D E"
 }